09 Iron 883 wont start
I bought an 09 Iron 883 from a friend of mine yesterday he informed me it had been sitting a while but he would occasionally go out and crank it and top the gas off with new gas every so often. I dont know how long it was sitting but before it was parked it was his daily. We jumped the bike off of his car and I drove it home yesterday knowing it needed a new battery, I bought a battery today and installed it turned on the ignition made sure it was in neutral and the clutch was pulled and tried to start it but only got a click. the lights all turn on and dim a bit when it tries to start, I was in a rush today so didnt really get a chance to look into it so I havent checked any fuses or anything but I was wondering if the fuses are good what should be the next step to check and try to nail down the issue. I also hooked it up to a trickle charger for about 4 hours and tried to crank again and had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the kickstand up? IIRC, Harley's have a built in switch which won't let it start if the kickstand is down.

The kick stand was down. i didnt think that would be the issue since the kick stand was down when we jumped the bike off when i picked it up but i will try it when i get off work tonight. thanks for the tip ill let you know what i find

No luck with having kick stand up

Does the engine turn over at all? Or when you press the start button does the starter do nothing?

Turned out to be a loose ground from the frame of the bike to the battery

Turned out to be a loose ground connection to the frame of the bike from the battery
